# how to restart video if phone goes to sleep

Tags: android, sleep, resume, media-player

So far i am making progress with a video app i am working on using the media player and a looping function. After a few tests, I am concerned the app will be a battery hog if i cannot stop the video loop when the phone reaches the sleep state. Can anyone give me a quick me a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I never implemented media player on android but i suggest that you keep the screen on with the xml attribute keepscreenon, as users watching videos are usually don't touch the screen and are likly expecting the screen not shutting down. 
But if you insist than i think you need to save the current time of the video in onpuase and resume the video from the saved time in onresume.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I  added a stop function to the media player that stops the video when the app is no longer visible on the screen. Still testing but so far its saving battery power and is functioning flawlessly.

Comment: I don't know the functionality of your stop function. But if you don't do it yet, remember the path and the cursor position in the video in sqlite or xml or .txt. Anything really. In this case your application has no "need" to stay alive. And on restarting/resuming,m just retrieve the last played data and set the cursor to whatever time in the video it was at when saved and enjoy the rest of the video.